# ASP.NET MVC AsyncController xxxCompleted

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynccontroller

When implementing ASP.NET MVC AsyncController the xxxCompleted method has to be Public.  I'm wondering if this means the xxxCompleted method can be invoked directly, or if this is protected internally using NonAction or something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Internally (and simplistically), there's an array of `MethodInfo` of the actions on the async controller constructed. When it's constructed the `Async` and `Completed` suffixes are stripped off the action method names.

If you try an call an action method such as `IndexCompleted` this array is searched but because there isn't an `IndexCompleted` in the array (because the suffixes have been removed) the `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` reports that no action was found.

It's worth having a poke around the source code to see for yourself:

> [ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM on CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742)